# Angular scroll in Div covered by other divs hidden by *ngIf

Tags: html, css, angular, overflow

I am developing a website with Angular and I have a card, which can select a text on a menu on the left. All the texts will be displayed by *ngIf. The Problem is, that if the first and lowest layer has an overflow and you want to scroll it doesn't work, because of the other texts being above it but disabled by *ngIf.

I found it out by using only one Layer and it worked fine. Is there any way to make the Disabled texts by *ngIf completely vanish so it doesn't block my scroll on the Layers below?
Thanks for help and I am sorry for my English.

This is the HTML code of the Card Component:

```
<div class="wrapper"> <!--Remove -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="item1">{{headLine}}</div>
    <div class="item2">
        <ul class="partList">
            <a *ngFor="let i of array" (click)="onClickPart(i)" class="part{{i}}"><li>{{prefix}}{{i}}</li></a>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!--Relevant Div -->
    <div *ngFor="let i of array" class="item3">
         <p *ngIf="part == i">{{texts[i-1]}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item4"><img src="../../assets/Spartans2.jpg" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

This is the CSS code: I took the Grid Display to Develop the Card. You can ignore all the comments

```
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 70px 140px 140px 140px 140px 140px;
    grid-template-rows: 70px 120px 120px;
    border-radius: 71px;
    // background: #e0e0e0;
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
}

.item1 {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 7;
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-row-end: 2;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-top-left-radius: 71px;
    border-top-right-radius: 71px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-bottom: none;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.item2 {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 2;
    grid-row-start: 2;
    grid-row-end: 4;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 71px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-right: none;
}

.item3 {
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: 4;
    grid-row-start: 2;
    grid-row-end: 4;
    // border-bottom-right-radius: 71px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: auto;
    // -ms-overflow-style: none;
    // scrollbar-width: none;
}

// .item3::-webkit-scrollbar {
//     display: none;
// }

.item4 {
    grid-column-start: 4;
    grid-column-end: 7;
    grid-row-start: 2;
    grid-row-end: 4;
    // background: url('../../assets/Spartans2.jpg');
    // background-repeat: no-repeat;
    // background-position: center;
    // background-size: cover;
    // background-attachment: fixed;
    object-fit: conatain;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-left: none;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 71px;
}

.item4 img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.partList {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    // justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    gap: 15px;
}

.partList a {
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.partList a:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.part1 {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Please share the relevant code. Also, are your text elements individually in some other div/element, which are, in turn, inside the menu? If it is so, and your ngIf is on text element, try moving the ngIf higher, to text element's parent. For example, if your structure is something like: menu > div1 > text1, menu > div2 > text2 etc. and you have the ngIf on text element, move it to div element.

Comment: thx, thats what did resolve it in the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried some more things and I found a resolution.
I removed the *ngFor loop and *ngIf statement. Instead I just changed the text in the div. So now we dont have 4 divs laying on top of each other but we have one that is changing its Value. I am just wondering how exactly the *ngIf works. Is it just making it Invisible or is it hiding it completely?

```
<div class="wrapper"> <!--Remove -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="item1">{{headLine}}</div>
    <div class="item2">
        <ul class="partList">
            <a *ngFor="let i of array" (click)="onClickPart(i)" class="part{{i}}"><li>{{prefix}}{{i}}</li></a>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="item3">
        {{currentText}}
    </div>
    <div class="item4"><img src="../../assets/Spartans2.jpg" alt=""></div>
</div>
```